# Submitting a form into an iframe in another page

Tags: forms, iframe, form-submit, target

I have a web page called `index1.aspx` that contains an iFrame called `main_iframe`.
In another page called `index2.aspx` I have an iFrame called `iframe2`

Now, my problem is that I'm trying to submit a form in `index2.aspx > iframe2` and the results target to be the `main_iframe` on `index1.aspx`